# Windows 11 Installation - Keyboard stops working after ISO install (Dell Inspiron 15R SE)

Tags: laptop, windows-11, dell

I'm attempting a clean **Windows 11** install from the official msft **ISO** (mounted on a USB drive) on a Dell Inspiron 15R laptop. During the installation procedure I go with a completely clean partition and the installation completes normally, I'm able to input my network info, and microsoft account info, using the laptop keyboard.

After the installation finishes and I'm left with the lock screen, **both the laptop keyboard and the touchpad mouse don't work anymore** (they worked fine during setup).

Comment: Are you missing the Dell Drivers.   Try running a Dell System Reset.

Comment: @John- How exactly does the author do that if they don't have a functional mouse and keyboard?

Comment: (a) Author said keyboard works when first installing.   (b) OP  Ctrl-Alt-Del, Task Manager, top menu,  run admin command :  systemreset.

Comment: @John - The author said Windows installed.  It just after Windows has been installed neither device is functional. So are you suggesting they perform a system reset from the lock screen, after already, just installed Windows?

Comment: Yes I am suggesting a proper reset

Comment: (If you have) you can use another computer to download the drivers into a USB drive and plug in some USB mouse and keyboard to install them.

Comment: @John that's exactly the issue, I don't have access to a usable mouse/keyboard right now (I do have one, but it uses a custom logitech usb thing which probably requires their own drivers, and it's not working).

Comment: That is why I am suggesting a proper install to get going.  Can be done with the Dell recovery USB or via Ctr-Alt-Del function at first start up

Answer (score 1):

> I'm attempting a clean Windows 11 install

All major vendors (Dell, Lenovo, HP) provide OEM machines where the main drivers are tailored for their machines.

The best way forward and the closest way to a clean install is to start with the Vendor's Recovery ISO (usually the Recovery Partition on the machine).

Install that fully and do all updates.

The reason for this is to get the Dell Mouse, Power, Network and like drivers plus Dell BIOS (UEFI) that can be later updated by Dell.

Now remove the Dell Apps you do not want using Programs and Features.

The other way is to set the apps not to start up (Task Manager or Autoruns).  This works as well.

Manufacturers have learn to generally make their app well behaved.